# Angular 2 dynamic create select and set selected option (edit operation)

Tags: angular

im trying to edit user. That user have non primitive array of machines. On edit i want to create new elements with select option and set that select option to value from user object:

```
export class User{
    constructor(
        private id: number,
        private name: string,
        private machines: Machine[]
    ){}
}

export class Machine{
    constructor(
        private id: number,
        private name: string,
        private price: string
    ){}
}
```

got json:

```
users =[  
        {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"Mike",
            "machines":[  
                {  
                    "id":1,
                    "name":"bike",
                    "price":"10"
                },
                {  
                    "id":2,
                    "name":"boat",
                    "price":"100"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
machines =[  
        {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"bike",
            "price":"10"
        },
        {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"boat",
            "price":"100"
        },
        {  
            "id":3,
            "name":"car",
            "price":"50"
        }
    ]
```

On edit i want to set select value to the corresponding object of machine from user.

```
<div *ngFor="let machine of user.machines;  let i = index">
    <label>Pick machine</label>
    <div>
        <select name="machine" [(ngModel)]="user.machines[i]">
            <option *ngFor='let mach of machines' [ngValue]='mach' >{{mach.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is in this:

[image]

The both select options are setted to the last one.

**UPDATE (Solution):**

Forgot to mention, that div is inside [Template-Driven form](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html).

```
<form #f="ngForm" *ngIf="user" (submit)="updateUser(f.valid)" novalidate>
    <div *ngFor="let machine of user.machines;  let i = index">
        <label>Pick machine</label>
        <div>
            <select name="machine" [(ngModel)]="user.machines[i]">
                <option *ngFor='let mach of machines' [ngValue]='mach' >{{mach.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

If in form the name of element is actually submitted.

> Each input element has a name property that is required by Angular
>   Forms to register the control with the form.

By adding unique name i solved my problem:

```
<select name="machine_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="user.machines[i]">
                <option *ngFor='let mach of machines' [ngValue]='mach' >{{mach.name}}</option>
```

Comment: The problem is, when binding with `ngModel` and `ngValue` it expects the same object reference. `user.machine[0]` and `machines[0]` have the same structure and content, but are not pointing to the same object in memory, hence it won't work.

Comment: They point to the same, in .ts i setted this.user.machines[i] = this.machines[j], otherwise it should not show anything

Comment: great , *attribute "name" need to be unique*. Thank You

Answer (score -1):

You should set the value of `ngModel` of particular index of array:

```
 <div *ngFor="let machine of user.machines;  let i = index">
        <label>Pick machine</label>
        <div>
            <select name="machine"  [(ngModel)]="machine.id">
              //or you can set the 'id' direct
               <option *ngFor='let mach of machines' [ngValue]='mach' >{{mach.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: machine is an object from array of objects...yea and i set it on particular index of array with this user.machines[i]

Comment: Then you should use it : `[(ngModel)]="machine.id"`

Comment: i cant do that when i have an object binding, not id (primitive type) binding