# How to make a dynamic form in Angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, ngmodel

I want to update some data from the server. I display those in a form to be able to change the values and submit it.

Here is my form.template.html :

```
<form #form = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(form.value)" >
    <div *ngFor=" let data of userData ">
            <label>{{data.libelle}}</label>
                <input 
                    type="text"
                    [(ngModel)] = "data.value"> 
            </div>
    <button type="submit">Enregistrer</button>
</form>
```

Here is my onSumit method in my form.component.ts

```
onSubmit(form) {
    console.log(form.value);
    // update values 
}
```

Problems are :

1) console.log  display `undefinded`

2)
[(ngModel)] displays only the last data.value (3 inputs, 3 same values)

`<input value = "{{data.value}}" >` works fine (3 inputs, 3 values corresponding to the right label)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please check my question and solution in question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149537/angular-2-dynamic-create-select-and-set-selected-option-edit-operation

Comment: this case is explain in the documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html